# Is there a better way to do CSS gradient borders?

Tags: css, border, gradient

I've found some ways to do pseudo gradient borders.
Here's mine, which is also compatible IE8-9.

http://www.jsfiddle.net/Zwhq8/

Do you think it's possible to do better, while keeping its gradient flexibility and beeing IE compatible ?

Comment: I saw a tutorial awhile back, which made use of the `:before` and `:after` pseudo-elements. I'll try to find it and post a link.

Comment: I've found something similar [here](http://designshack.net/articles/css/the-lowdown-on-before-and-after-in-css/), under 'a brief example'.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there have you tried this?
The very last example does (I think) what you would like

http://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/